# Evaluation of expressions within an if statement

Tags: c#, syntax

While refactoring some code written by someone else, I've come across some weirdness that I don't understand, and I'm hoping someone can explain why it happens.

```
if (mystring.Length != (mystring = mystring.Replace("!#", replacement)).Length)
{
    i = 1;
}
else if (mystring.Length != (mystring = mystring.Replace("#", replacement)).Length)
{
    i = -1;
}
```

What I *thought* would happen here would be that as brackets have the highest precedence, the assignment inside the brackets would happen first and none of the code inside the if and else if blocks would be executed.
Here is what I thought this code was effectively doing:

```
mystring = mystring.Replace("!#", replacement);
if (mystring.Length != mystring.Length)
{
    i = 1;
}
else
{
    mystring = mystring.Replace("#", replacement);
    if (mystring.Length != mystring.Length)
    {
        i = -1;
    }
}
```

I thought that the only thing that would happen would be the changes to `mystring`, as the assignment would be made before the comparison. Testing this out has shown that what happens is actually closer to this:

```
string temp1 = mystring.Replace("!#", replacement);
string temp2 = mystring.Replace("#", replacement);
if (mystring.Length != temp1.Length)
{
    i = 1;
}
else if (mystring.Length != temp2.Length)
{
    i = -1;
}
if (i == 1)
{
    mystring = temp1;
}
else
{
    mystring = temp2;
}
```

If that isn't clear, what I think is happening is that the assignment to mystring is being made after the truth of the expression is evaluated, rather than as the first part of evaluating that expression as I had thought. My third piece of code might not get that across very well but I can't think of a better way to express it!

In short:

1. Will my third code snippet always give the same result as the first?
2. *Why* doesn't the first code snippet do the same thing as the second?

Comment: The difficulty in reasoning about this kind of code is exactly why it should raise a red flag.

Comment: This is exactly why boolean expressions shouldn't have side effects.

Comment: I'm going to rewrite it to make it more readable, I just want to make sure I don't change what it does in the process! (And now I'm curious about what's going on)

Comment: What makes you believe the assignment is happening *after* the `if` evaluation?

Comment: @CodingGorilla see Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: @CodingGorilla if mystring contains "!#" and replacement is for example "zzz", at the end of the first example i == 1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Precedence isn't about *ordering* operations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/10/precedence-vs-order-redux.aspx) - it's about *binding* operations together. The execution order is *always* left to right. So for example, if you write:

```
int a = x * (y / z);
```

then `x` is still evaluated before `y / z`.

So in this expression:

```
if (mystring.Length != (mystring = mystring.Replace("!#", replacement)).Length)
```

we have:

- Evaluate `mystring.Length` (we'll call this value *x*)
- Evaluate `(mystring = mystring.Replace("!#", replacement)).Length`

  - Evaluate `mystring.Replace("!#", replacement)`
  - Assign the result to `mystring`
  - Take the length (we'll call this value *y*)
- Compare *x* and *y*

As is clear from the confusion, this code is horrible - I'm glad you're refactoring it away from its current form.

Comment: Doesn't this back up the OP's original understanding of what would happen?  The assignment of result to mystring should be happening before the comparision, his comment indicates to me that he believes the assignment happens **after** the comparison.

Comment: @CodingGorilla not to be pedantic but "her comment" please!

Comment: @CodingGorilla: My reading of the question suggested that the OP believed that the RHS of the `!=` operator would execute before the LHS was evaluated.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, I could probably have phrased it better!

Answer (score 0):

The code within your original is actually closer to:

```
int length1 = mystring.Length;
mystring = mystring.Replace("!#", replacement); // First nested paren on RHS
int length2 = mystring.Length; // second "length" check on RHS
if (length1 != length2)
{
    i = 1;
}
```

This is because the execution order will be left to right.

This causes the length of the string to be determined, *then* the string is mutated, then the length is fetched and compared.

Note that this type of code is almost always something that should be avoided.  Mutating data within a boolean expression is almost always a bad idea, and mutating the same data you're checking makes this very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

1: No. In your first code snippet the **mystring** variable changes **in both if and else** to evaluate the comparison expression. So to have the same result change the third code snippet to:

```
string temp1 = mystring.Replace("!#", replacement);
string temp2 = **temp1**.Replace("#", replacement);
if (mystring.Length != temp1.Length)
{
    i = 1;
}
....
```

2: Because **mystring** changes exactly two times